# Trying to set up a html popup in Python, using folium to fit images sizes

Tags: python, image, popup, marker, folium

I am trying to write this code to display **popups** using **folium** on a default map. The following loop is searching through my **database** for the location of each **point**, to display the picture belonging to it. The code works nicely, but I cannot customize the size of the image to fit the **iframe** belonging to the popup. I want the popup to show up **without any scroll bars**.  Any suggestions?

This is the code:

```
for i in range(0, len(locationlist)):
    folium.Marker(
        locationlist[i],
        popup = folium.Popup(IFrame('<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,
{}">'.format(base64.b64encode(open(df6['path'][i], 'rb').read()).decode()), 
width=500, height=300), max_width=500),
        icon = folium.Icon(color='green')
        ).add_to(m)
```

This is an example of how the image in the popup looks right now: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RTfCP.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try fitting the image into the **iframe** by writing into the **html code** something like this:

```
<img style="width:100%; height:100%;">
```

Answer (score 0):

A workaround is to reduce your image size before running the script. But there must be a clever way to do this.